# Only show specific ngIf item

Tags: ionic3, angular5, angular6

I have created an `toggle-show-more-items` component which is a button which shows more values. But if I have multiple `toggle-show-more-items` components it opens them all. How can I target a specific item I will show you below how I did it right now.

```
<div *ngFor="let bucketName of bucketNames" [hidden]="!getBucketsWithValues(bucketName.criterium).length">
  <ng-container *ngIf="bucketName.toon_maximaal && open">
    <div *ngFor="let bucket of getBucketsWithValues(bucketName.criterium) | orderBy:'key'; let ndx = index">
         <osi-checkbox *ngIf="ndx >= bucketName.toon_maximaal" 
            [model]="filter[bucketName.criterium][bucket.key].checked" 
            (change)="onFilterChange(filter[bucketName.criterium][bucket.key], $event.checked)">

            <osi-li-body class="osi-black-87">{{ bucket.key }}&nbsp;({{ bucket.doc_count }})</osi-li-body>

         </osi-checkbox>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <div *ngIf="bucketName.toon_maximaal && getBucketsWithValues(bucketName.criterium).length > bucketName.toon_maximaal">
    <toggle-show-more-item [openTitle]="'OWC.SHOW_MORE' | translate | uppercase" [closeTitle]="'OWC.SHOW_LESS' | translate | uppercase" 
         [padding]="false" (onToggleClick)="showMore($event)"></toggle-show-more-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the showMore method:

```
showMore(open) {
   this.open = open;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **indexes**

Add a `open` property to every item of the bucketNames array, so that you will be able to set if an item is in "showMore mode" or not.

Instead of

```
*ngFor="let bucketName of bucketNames"
```

Use

```
*ngFor="let bucketName of bucketNames; let i = index"
```

Then change your showMore function :

```
(onToggleClick)="showMore($event, i)"
```

And adapt it in your ts :

```
showMore(open, index) {
   this.bucketNames[index].open = open; // Access only the element at given index
}
```

You will also need to change your component *ngIf :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="bucketName.toon_maximaal && bucketName.open">
```

---

As an alternative to the component method you can set open in the template as well.

```
(onToggleClick)="bucketNames[i].open = $event"
```

Comment: Oh wauw thank you this is the solution!! Will accept the answer in 2 min

Comment: Just to add to this answer, you can set open in the template without the method as well. (onToggleClick)="bucketNames[i].open = $event"

Comment: @Marshal great comment will use this you could edit his answer hope he approve this.

Comment: Indeed this is cleaner :)